# VBA Type Mismatch when returning string to a value

Tags: vba, if-statement, type-mismatch

Fairly new to VBA but I have the following function that runs up until the Workbooks(PDwb).Sheets("pivotdata").Range("E2").Value = "ON-HAND" then returns a Tpye Mismatch Error.

The full code checks a cell from a different workbook so I don't know if that is causing the error.

```
Function IfCheck(Cell As Variant)

    If Cell = "ON_HAND" Or Cell = "ON HAND" Then
        Set PDwb = ActiveWorkbook
        Workbooks(PDwb).Sheets("pivotdata").Range("E2").Value = "ON-HAND"
    Else
        Set PDwb = ActiveWorkbook
        Workbooks(PDwb).Sheets("pivotdata").Range("E2").Value = Cell
    End If

    Set BOwb = ActiveWorkbook

End Function
```

I can't for the life of me work out what to do differently :S

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Workbooks(PDwb)` function expects a string as parameter. But `PDwb` already IS the workbook.

Try

```
PDwb.Sheets("pivotdata").Range("E2").Value = "ON-HAND"
```

Comment: Thanks Fraty that seems to have cleared it up but now I'm getting a Subscript out of Range error.

Comment: Are you sure there is a sheet called 'pivotdata' in your workbook?

Comment: Managed to fix this issue, I moved the function into the sub and will run it from there. Thanks for the help